# Passing a general function as arguments in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, parameter-passing

I'm making a form with validation in React.js. Is there a way that I can pass a "general" function in as parameters? I have functions that validate each of the inputs in the form. For example, if I have:

```
updateState(e) {
        if (this.validateEmail(e.target.value) === true) {
            this.setState({[e.target.className]: e.target.value});
            this.setState({errorMsg: 'Valid'});
            document.getElementById(e.target.className).className = "green";
        }
        else if (e.target.value.length === 0) {
            this.setState({errorMsg: 'Empty submission'});
            document.getElementById(e.target.className).className = "red";
        }
        else {
            this.setState({errorMsg: 'Invalid form input'});
            document.getElementById(e.target.className).className = "red";
        }
}
```

I want to be able to pass in functions such as validateName, validateEmail, validateAddress so it looks like this:

```
updateState(e, parameterFunction) {
            if (this.parameterFunction(e.target.value) === true) {
                this.setState({[e.target.className]: e.target.value});
                this.setState({errorMsg: 'Valid'});
                document.getElementById(e.target.className).className = "green";
            }
            else if (e.target.value.length === 0) {
                this.setState({errorMsg: 'Empty submission'});
                document.getElementById(e.target.className).className = "red";
            }
            else {
                this.setState({errorMsg: 'Invalid form input'});
                document.getElementById(e.target.className).className = "red";
            }
    }
```

Is this possible?

Thanks all, this is my first StackOverflow question!

Comment: Don't overthink it. Functions are first-class entities in JavaScript -- just pass them around like you would anything else!

Comment: @shabs thanks for your response. So would the example I put above work if I called it with validateEmail as a parameter?

Comment: Yup, other than the `this` point that Dloeda makes below. Their answer below is more tailored to your specific example, so I'll just offer something generic for the sake of demonstration:

`const double = n => n + n;`

`const applyFunction = (n, f) => f(n)`

`applyFunction(1, double)`

`// ==> 2`

(edit: is there a better way to format a code block in a comment?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do it, but this function is not defined in your `this` object, it's just like another variable, just call it!

```
function updateState(e, validateName, validateEmail, validateAddress) {
    var data = e.target.value;

    if (validateName(data.name) && validateEmail(data.mail) && validateAddress(data.address) {
            //Do some stuff
    }
}
```